How do I get Radio Controls in a Group Box to produce an OnClick event
I have a group box to which a number of radio buttons have been added. I am not using a TRadioGroup because it doesn't give me the layout I want. According to the Delphi 11 documentation for TGroupBox Events, "Ususally, OnClick occurs when the user presses and releases the left mouse button with the mouse pointer over the control. This event can also occur when .... the Checked property of a radio button is set to True". My problem is that is doesn't. Agreed, it does say "Usually" but perhaps there is a workaround? If the GroupBox responds, I should be able to identify the button that was checked. None of the radio buttons have on OnClick routine in place.
